# Alternativas para o Firebase FCM?

Tags: php, push-notification

Gostaria de saber se há alternativas para a realizarmos envio de notificações push sem o uso do Firebase (Google).

O objetivo é enviar mensagens push como notificação simples ou do tipo que contém JSON data, de um servidor, com sistema desenvolvido em PHP, para dispositivos clientes (Browsers ou SmartPhones).

Comment: Tem uma da Amazon, não lembro o nome e não lembro se funciona pra Browser. Você também pode tentar fazer sua própria solução baseada em chamadas assíncronas de uma página web sendo feitas em _background_, mas não recomendo fazer isso em produção; recomendaria fazer uma solução caseira se você quisesse descobrir como funciona (portanto, teste e não produção) ou se deseja fazer um concorrente ao FCM

Comment: Note que para iOS você precisa falar com a APN, que é um mundo à parte é que o FCM oferece uma camada de abstração em relação a isso

Comment: Obrigado @JeffersonQuesado , muito esclarecedor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duas boas opções:

1. https://aws.amazon.com/pt/sns/
2. https://onesignal.com/

Atualmente eu uso OneSignal, é gratuito e não tem nenhum limite de acesso aos recursos ou quantidade de notificações